# TypeError: Cannot read property 'memberCount' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

```js
    var computers = new Map();
    const mems = client.guilds.cache.get("serverid"); 

    mems.memberCount.forEach(member => {
        computers.set(member.user.id, 0);
        console.log(computers.get(member.user.id));
    });
```

its occurring on this line:

```js
mems.memberCount.forEach(member => {
```

I know that memberCount is incorrect but I can't find what the correct term is

Comment: Since mems is undefined, I would look at what the call to `client.guilds.cache.get("serverid")` is actually doing.

Comment: `console.log(mems);`

Comment: This is impossible to answer because we don’t know what is being assigned to mems, hence the seemingly useless comments. Like this one.

Comment: That `get()` can return either a Guild object, or `undefined` when there is no guild with that ID in the cache.
Additionally, `undefined` would always be returned if you would try to get a guild before your bot logs in - for example if your code would be outside of any event listener - as `client.guilds` does not contain any data when created, but gets populated from data received from Discord upon successful login.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do but this should workout.
[Guild#memberCount](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=memberCount) returns a [number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) so basically you can't loop over it. From what i see you trying to add each member with a value 0 in a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

You need to loop over [Guild#members](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=members) and add it to the Map you created.

```js
const computers = new Map();
const server = client.guilds.cache.get("server id");
// if server is not found we will return.
if (!server) return;
server.members.forEach(member => computers.set(member.id, 0));
// or
server.membeers.map(member => computers.set(member.id, 0));

// now you can log computers to find out what you wanna do with it next.
```

[Guild#members](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=members) returns a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/general/welcome) of cached members in the server. and you can use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) or [map](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=map) to get the member from the Collection.

Note: Collection extends Map

Comment: I'm trying to make a map so I can count how many 'computers' each member has